# How to fix an 'Invalid tag name' in WSDL request using Zeep?

Tags: wsdl, lxml, python-3.7, zeep

When trying to access a WSDL service, I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Invalid tag name 'Foo\\Bar\\Baz\\Etc\\V3Port'
```

The port which is provided through the WSDL-link actually has single backslashes: **'Foo\Bar\Baz\Etc\V3Port'**

The ValueError gets raised when zeep calls the apihelpers.pxi method in the lxml library.

Any idea how I can fix this?

*(BTW: the script worked fine when I used it 2 months ago. The WSDL-link hasn't changed)*

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution

Before, it was sufficient to do:

```
from zeep import Client
```

Now, apparently, I need to explicitly add:

```
from lxml import etree
```

Everything works as before now.

Answer (score 0):

Zeep does not like like "/" in values also. It gives invalid tag name error any time it finds any character in value that it does not like. For all such errors, you need to  modify as_qname function in utils.py located in root folder of zeep library.

In my case, it was complaining for "/" in value, which is a valid value. I had to add below line to as_qname function.

```
value = value.replace("/", "-")
```

Below are first few lines of as_qname after modification

```
def as_qname(value: str, nsmap, target_namespace=None) -> etree.QName:
    """Convert the given value to a QName"""
    value = value.strip()  # some xsd's contain leading/trailing spaces
    value = value.replace("/", "-")   # Added by me.
    if ":" in value:
        prefix, local = value.split(":")
```